# BaseGameActivity cannot be resolved

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to implement the Google Play API into my Application.
Google says to import BaseGameUtils as library and add this library to my project:

[image]

this "main" is the BaseGameUtils, I have no idea why it's called "main".

However, here You can see that it's the BaseGameUtils project:
[image]

As You may see, there are the three classes, BaseGameActivity, GameHelper and BaseHelperUtils.

No when I try to import the BaseGameActivity I get following:

[image]

But strangely, I can import

```
com.google.example.games.basegameutils.*;
```

But when importing this, I still can't use the BaseGameActivity.class

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you follow all of the steps from the documentation?

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: Yes I did follow the instructions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that you have done wrong is that you are trying to import BaseGameActivity into your application project.

I am assuming that you have already done this:

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Then follow this:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart

In essence, you import the TypeANumber and BaseGameUtils code from the Android samples into your workspace (not into your application project).

Then you confirm that both Google Play services and BaseGameUtils are defined as library projects (Properties .. Android .. Is Library should be checked).

Then IN YOUR APP PROJECT add them as references (Properties .. Android .. Reference ..Add)

But I have just emphasised key steps that I suspect you may have misunderstood or omitted. You have to follow the whole thing carefully. Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I really might have overseen that part. I got very confused with all these tutorials offered by Google... I will check that up.

Comment: No problem. It took a lot of people a long time to get this working last year, but the documentation is now much better and, I believe, very accurate.